# Discrepancy in API Response Structure Between Frontend and Backend

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, client

Description:
I am facing an issue where the structure of the response from my backend API differs when called from the frontend. The expected JSON structure returned by the backend API includes nested objects and arrays, but the frontend receives a simplified JSON structure without the nested data. As a result, processing the data correctly on the client-side becomes challenging.

Backend Code:
The backend API code snippet is as follows:

```js
export async function GET(
  req: Request,
  { params }: { params: { productId: string } }
) {
  try {
    // ...other code

    const product = await prismadb.product.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: params.productId,
      },
      include: {
        images: true,
        category: true,
        size: true,
        color: true,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(product);
  } catch (error) {
    // ...error handling
  }
}
```

Frontend Code:
The frontend code snippet responsible for fetching the data is as follows:

```js
import { Product } from "@/types";

const URL = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/products`;

const getProduct = async (id: string): Promise<Product> => {
  const url = `${URL}/${id}`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
  return data;
};

export default getProduct;
```

Observations:

- When making the API request directly from tools like Postman or running the backend API independently, the expected JSON structure is returned, including nested objects and arrays.
- However, when calling the API from the frontend using `fetch` or `axios`, the response structure is altered, and the nested objects and arrays are missing.
- The request URL and ID in the frontend code are properly defined and aligned with the backend API endpoint.
- There are no cross-origin issues
- The frontend code includes appropriate TypeScript interfaces to match the expected response structure.

Comment: are you sure?  Have you actually looked at the response in the network tab rather than just the response that is logged to the console?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the network tab and it was calling the same API.